# set backgroundcolor as UIColor.systembackground in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

Hey i have a Navigation beside my list.

I want that a active navigationitem has the same backgroundcolor as the list.

But i dont see any way to get the color (With compatible Light/Dark mode switch)

I want to set the bluecolor as the systembackground like the right item.

[image: navpic]

my code now is like following.

```
NavigationLink(destination: PersonView()) {
    VStack
    {
        Image("Company").resizable().frame(width:40, height:40).colorMultiply(Color(red: 57 / 255, green: 214 / 255, blue: 155 / 255))
        Text("Companies").foregroundColor(Color(red: 57 / 255, green: 214 / 255, blue: 155 / 255))
    }
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
.padding(16)
.background(Color(.systemBlue))
```

Answer (score 6):

on iOS

```
Color(UIColor.systemBackground)
```

on macOS use

```
Color.init(_ color: NSColor)
```

NSColor define different background colors for different usage ...
for example

```
NSColor.controlBackgroundColor
```

or

```
NSColor.textBackgroundColor
```

and so on. Check the documentation.

Comment: Hey, thank you. But when i use it i get this: error: use of unresolved identifier 'UIColor'

Comment: do you speek about iOS or macOS?

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. I already tried all nscolors of the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/ui_element_colors But none of them is like my list background on macos

Comment: your List .... did you set its background? Or where is that List from?

Comment: Hey, it's an swiftui list loop where i fetch data from a json and display it. i didn't changed nothing. its a macos app

Comment: loop ??? List is not a loop :-), but ok. List is container View. It contains some other Views (aka rows). Do you have a code for it?

Comment: sorry i thought it is one. ;) Im pretty new to swiftui. I uploaded the two relevant views here. https://pastebin.com/mj2H3ZBe . Is it possible that the system accent color overwrites/changes the background color? it feel like so when i change it to purple ...

Comment: ok, i see ... try Color.init(NSColor.controlBackgroundColor), it is default behavior of List background, based on my try ... (black by default, even in light mode). Better you set both List.background(Color.xxx) and your VStack.background(Color.xxx) where xxx is the same color representation.

Comment: Thank you, i tried this color but it isn't the default in my case i also tried to set the vstack and list background to the         .background(Color(.controlBackgroundColor)) but this isn't filling the hole list, just the items..

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for a fast portable solution between iOS and MacOS (notes from user3441734 do apply, yet) Below a complete small sample from Apple stock template for SwiftUi app.
(as a bonus "label", too)

Hope can help others.

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

#if os(iOS)
import UIKit
public typealias EZColor    = UIColor
#elseif os(macOS)
import AppKit
public typealias EZColor    = NSColor
#endif


public extension EZColor {
    #if os(macOS)
    static var label: EZColor {
        return EZColor.labelColor
    }

    static var systemFill: EZColor {
        return NSColor.windowBackgroundColor // works for label, but it's a patch
        //return NSColor.controlColor // works, better for controls, but it's a patch
    }
    #endif
}


public extension Color {
    static var systemFill: Color {
        return Color(EZColor.systemFill)
    }
}



struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            //Text("Hello, world!").background(Color(EZColor.systemFill))
            //Text("Hello, world!").background(Color.systemFill)
            Text("Hello, world!").background(Color.systemFill)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```